# make org-mode temporarily emulate traditional outlining keybindings?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, outliner

Most of the time, org-mode's keybindings M-return to create a heading, and TAB to cycle visibility, are quite useful.

But sometimes when brainstorming, it would be useful to use org-mode to create a traditional hierarchical bulleted list (of course using stars instead of bullets), and using the traditional keybindings used by outlining apps like Workflowy, Evernote, Taskpaper, etc:

- <kbd>return</kbd> creates the next item in the bulleted list
- <kbd>tab</kbd> demotes the item in the hierarchy
- <kbd>S-tab</kbd> promotes the item in the hierarchy

In org terms, this would mean:

- <kbd>return</kbd> binds to M-return
- <kbd>tab</kbd> binds to M-right
- <kbd>S-tab</kbd> binds to M-left

Is there some kind of org minor mode that will allow me to (temporarily)
run org like it's a traditional outlining app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is any existing minor mode that will do the trick, however one such as this should work:

```lisp
(define-minor-mode zin/org-outline-mode
  "" nil
  :lighter " OOut"
  :keymap (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
            (define-key map (kbd "<return>") 'org-meta-return)
            (define-key map (kbd "<tab>") 'org-metaright)
            (define-key map (kbd "S-<tab>") 'org-metaleft)
            map))
```

Comment: Totally works! Others, note too that you one also start with a `- ` to outline using a list instead of using headlines.

Comment: It won't disable any of the other Org keybindings.  So every other command is still available (however no easy way to create newlines for content, or cycle visibility because the keys are used by this new minor mode).

Comment: What about defining a new file extension so that certain files were automatically opened in the outlining minor mode? You could define a new file extension (e.g. `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.ooo\\'" . org-mode))` but then how to automatically invoke the outline mode hook?